# Load a Railtie only for Server and Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, initializer

I am creating a gem for a Rails project and I got some troubles to 
understand how generators and initializers work. 
I would like to 
initialize my module loading some stuff from the database from models 
related to tables my gem should create with a migration file.

Problem is : if I create a Railtie and put it my gem lib directory, 
when I try to run my generator (to create the migration template file 
for example), it's already trying to run the Railtie even though 
tables required don't exist yet (because the migration file has not been executed yet).

How to restrict the "scope" of the Railtie ? I would like it only to 
run when booting Rails from a server (webrick, thin, ...) or from the 
console, but not for any rake tasks (including generators). I think 
that rake tasks (like generators) load the entire Rails environment 
and my problem should come from that. 
Is there a simpler way to do what I want ?

any help or advice appreciated.